# CMake link Qt5::Svg but not see by QImageReader

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I recently change my computer (Windows 10), so I reinstall CLion and Qt (using CMake compilation). But one of my project doesn't work anymore.

I have add Qt5::Svg into CMake, it compile but no SVG appears in application. And if I try a QImageReader::supportedImageFormats(), "SVG" is not listed.

I have Qt5Svgd.dll in build directory.

Here my CMake config :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(NBTModifier)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Svg REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
add_executable(
    NBTModifier

    main.cpp
    MainWindow/MainWindow.ui MainWindow/MainWindow.h MainWindow/MainWindow.cpp

    icons/breeze.qrc icons/breeze-dark.qrc
)
target_link_libraries(NBTModifier Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Svg)
```

Did I miss something ?

EDIT : According to [alexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11603875/alexandre) suggestion, I run DependencyWalker : My "NBTModifier.exe" doesn't seems to rely on Qt5Svgd.dll. It explains why QImageReader don't display it.

So why CMake doesn't link Qt5Svg  to my application ?

Comment: Maybe check with DependencyWalker (or Depends) if the SVG DLL's are correctly found and loaded when you run your software.

Comment: Good suggestion. Question updated : the DLL isn't linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display SVG images (ie. icons) in your application, you need the corresponding imageformat plugin, which is being loaded runtime (that's why it's not shown by DependenyWalker). Look into your `QTDIR/plugins/imageformats` dir, and look for `qsvg.dll` or `libqsvg.dll`, and if needed, copy it into your runtime dir. See https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/windows-deployment.html#qt-plugins for the corresponding documentation.

Comment: `Thanks, it works. Using theme system, i also add `platformthemes` and `iconengine`. However, i don't undersdand why i don't need them with my previous computer.

Comment: I would guess that on your previous system QTDIR was added to your PATH, so your executable found it even if it was not in its runtime dir. Setting up Qt development environment and running Qt apps on Windows is borderline black magic, at least for me, being a Unix/Linux guy... See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications for further details on dll lookup